# How to avoid stack build up?

Tags: java, recursion, stack, callstack, code-organization

I'm trying to figure out how I can write this method to avoid the stack buildup from recursively calling the method in the exception?

Here is the wording of my instructions:

> Read a number, use an exception handler to make sure it is an int number and then add to the ArrayList object, aryList.

Here is my attempt:

```
public void createOriginalAryList() {

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter a number: ");

      try {

         int number = keyboard.nextInt();
         aryList.add(number);

         while(keyboard.hasNextInt()) {

            System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
            number = keyboard.nextInt();
            aryList.add(number);

         }

      } catch(InputMismatchException ime) {
         System.out.println("Invalid number submitted! Try again.");
         createOriginalAryList();
      }

      System.out.println(aryList);
   }
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't use recursion for non-recursive problems. It's not a replacement for loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a `do-while` loop:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

boolean redo = false;
do {
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    redo = false;
    try {
       int number = keyboard.nextInt();
       aryList.add(number);

       while(keyboard.hasNextInt()) {

          System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
          number = keyboard.nextInt();
          aryList.add(number);

       }

    } catch(InputMismatchException ime) {
       redo = true;
       System.out.println("Invalid number submitted! Try again.");
    }
}
while(redo);
System.out.println(aryList);
```

Since initializing the `Scanner keyboard` each time is useless, it is put before the loop.

Comment: This answer is spot on - use loops to avoid unnecessary pushes to the stack

Comment: I knew I needed to use a do while but just couldn't see in my minds eye how to properly implement it.  Thank you!

Comment: If there wasn't a final statement after the loop. An intelligent Java-compiler could detect tail recursion and even remove the stack-thing. Automatically. Although there are even compilers who turn a method as presented here into a loop themselves.

Comment: Any idea why the first run makes me enter two numbers before it enters the `while(keyboard.hasNextInt())`?

Comment: In fact it will keep asking you this. A `keyboard.hasNextInt()` checks if there is an integer anywhere further on the input stream. Since you read from `stdin`, that stream will block until the user provides info.

Comment: Wait... before it enters the `while` loop? What numbers did you use?

Comment: I enter a number and press enter and nothing, I enter another number and press enter and then have a print statement inside of the `hasNextInt()` loop and then it works as it should.

Comment: Well what you do is you ask for a number, then it is added. And in the head of the second `while` loop the program blocks waiting for the next line.

Comment: How would you suggest I fix this?

Comment: If at least one argument is required, print the `System.out....` before entering the second `while` loop and at the end of the loop as well. In case it is not required, remove all lines asking for data before entering the second while loop.